# NGINX + Apache2 + codeigniter - Subpath not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, apache2

I currently have 2 PHP applications up and running on my DigitalOcean's Ubuntu server. There is a third one as well, but it's not working. All three PHP projects are configured to run on different ports.
Meanwhile, using NGINX server I have configured a reverse proxy. The configuration is as given below.

**/etc/nginx/nginix.conf**

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     IP;
        location / {
              #Assinged to a python project
        }
        location /php_project_1 {
            proxy_pass http://IP:5002;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        }

        location /php_project_2 {
            proxy_pass http://IP:5003;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        }
        location /php_project_3 {
            proxy_pass http://IP:5004;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;

        }
    }
```

I have also created 3 configuration files in **/etc/apache2/sites-available**.

**PROBLEM**

php_project_1 and php_project_2 are developed using core PHP and they work fine.

php_project_3 is developed using **codeigniter**. and that is the project which is causing me problems. Inside this project, under **/application/config/config.php** I have modified `$config['base_url']` and entered the values as **http://IP/php_project_3**.

However, when I hit the URL `http://IP/php_project_3`, I get a blank page. 
I also checked **/var/logs/apache2** and **/var/logs/nginx**, however, the error.log file does not show any messages corresponding to my request.

Meanwhile, I can successfully run the other 2 applications using `http://IP/php_project_1` and `http://IP/php_project_2`

I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the situation has gone a bit off topic. There are other issues on my side which might be a cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The value for `$config['base_url']` should end in a slash, so try

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://IP/php_project_3/';
```

If the above still produces a blank and there are no errors to be found in any log files at `/application/logs/` then you might have a BOM on one of your script files. I've run into them at the very beginning of the script before the opening `<?php`. Start with the controller. Delete that opening line, then retype it - test, repeat on any "view" files the controller uses until you find the offender.

You can see if the proxy is being delivered to the correct directory by temporarily replacing CodeIgniter's `index.php` with another file of the same name but with a simple text output, i.e.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
```

Obviously, if you see the text the problem lies outside of a server config issue.

Comment: Ok. I'll give this a try and get back. Thanks, @DFriend

Comment: There is a file called `index.html` inside /application/logs. Contains `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: That's there to prevent the server from returning a directory listing should someone try to browse to `http://IP/php_project_3/applications/logs/`

Comment: That same "default index file" is in several other directories that could potentially (accidentally) be publicly available.

Comment: oh, ok. Anyway, let me continue with the troubleshooting steps that you have guided me with.

Comment: In my Auth Controller, inside `index` function there is a line `redirect('Auth/login', 'refresh');`. If I echo anything before that, it works. If I echo anything inside `login` function in the same Auth controller, it does't echo anything.

Comment: Seeming more and more like a Byte Order Mark (BOM). These are not always easy to find as they are not visible in most text editors. Notepad++  makes it easy if you're running Windows.  I'm thinking Google may be helpful to learn ways to find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184735/discussion-between-abhilash-and-dfriend).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when running codeigniter behind trafik. After pulling all of my hair out I realized that it was because the IP of the traefik instance had to be included in the auth.conf file.